How will you come to work if you move to a farm? vs How do you come to work if you move to a farm?
My students are learning the first conditional in English and one of the exercises shows the next sentence: 
I know that the correct option in this case is 'Will you come' but the sentence 'How do you come/get to work if you move to a farm', makes sense to my nonnative ears, it doesn't seem to be wrong for me although I know that the natural option for native speakers would be 'will you come' so, what do you think?

Hi. Your suggested sentence doesn't really work. I think you know something is a bit off here.  It would need to be something like "How do you come to work if you have moved to a farm" or perhaps "if you live on a farm".  You would need to say that the "move" has already happened to be able to use the simple present tense "how do you come".

Thank you very much! Might you please tell me if you would still be able to understand the intended question's meaning? in other words on a scale from zero to ten, how awkward does it sound to you? I guess this sentence is not grammatically correct either.

I would understand it, but perhaps be a little confused if you ask how I do something when it hasn't happened yet. It's not logical.  I would immediately know you were probably a non-native speaker and probably just got the tenses mixed up.

I think even if the speaker was your boss, and this was part of a conversation taking place in the workplace, almost every native speaker would ask "How will you get to work...?" rather than "...come to work..."

Are you talking about the future or the present? In other words, do you live on a farm? "If" doesn't always express a conditional.

The simple present can express "general truths".
If the phrase "if you move to a farm" is understood not as a particular  future possibility but as a generic choice — "if one chooses to move out into the country"  vs "if one chooses to live in the city" —  then "how do you" becomes a valid form of the question, since it can be understood generically as well.
Compare:

If you mix white vinegar and baking soda together, what happens?

It will always happen.  So "What happens?" is grammatical. It need not be "What will happen?"
